Strong Convergence of Nets in a Norm-Closed $*$-Subalgebra of Bounded Operators
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B(H)}$ the set of all bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$. The norm topology on $\mathcal{B(H)}$ is defined using the operator norm. For a net $(x_\alpha)_\alpha$ in $\mathcal{B(H)}$, convergence $x_\alpha \to x$ in the norm topology means that $\|x_\alpha - x\| \to 0$. The strong topology on $\mathcal{B(H)}$ is defined using convergence on vectors in $\mathcal{H}$. For a net $(y_\alpha)_\alpha$ in $\mathcal{B(H)}$, convergence $y_\alpha \to y$ in the strong topology means that $y_\alpha \xi \to y \xi$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$.
Let $N \subseteq \mathcal{B(H)}$ be a $*$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B(H)}$, and let $A = \overline{N}^{\|\cdot\|}$ denote the norm closure of $N$. Define $N_+$ and $A_+$ as the sets of positive elements in $N$ and $A$, respectively. Suppose $(a_\lambda)_\lambda$ is a net in $A_+$ such that $a_\lambda \to 1$ strongly, where $1$ denotes the identity operator in $\mathcal{B(H)}$. That is, for every $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$, $\|a_\lambda \xi - \xi\| \to 0$.
We aim to construct a net $(b_\alpha)_\alpha$ in $N_+$ such that $b_\alpha \to 1$ strongly, using the given net $(a_\lambda)_\lambda$ in $A_+$.
Since $A = \overline{N}^{\|\cdot\|}$, for each $\lambda$, there exists a net $(a_{\lambda,\mu})_\mu \subseteq N_+$ such that $a_{\lambda,\mu} \to a_\lambda$ in the norm topology.
But I am unable to construct such $(b_\alpha)_\alpha$ using $(a_{\lambda,\mu})_\mu$ so that $b_\alpha \to 1$ strongly. I would be grateful for any assistance you can offer in this construction. Thank you for your time and effort.

For each $a_\lambda$, since $N$ is norm-dense in $A$, there exists a sequence $(x_{\lambda, m})_m \subset N$ s.t. $\lim_m x_{\lambda, m} = a_\lambda^{1/2}$. Thus, $\lim_m x_{\lambda, m}^\ast x_{\lambda, m} = a_\lambda$. For each $n \geq 1$, let $b_{\lambda, n} = x_{\lambda, m}^\ast x_{\lambda, m}$ for large enough $m$ s.t. $\|x_{\lambda, m}^\ast x_{\lambda, m} - a_\lambda\| < \frac{1}{n}$. Now define $(\lambda_1, n_1) \leq (\lambda_2, n_2)$ iff $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$ and $n_1 \leq n_2$. This defines a net, and it is now not hard to check $b_{\lambda, n} \to 1$ strongly.
